# Docker container slow to start monorepo apps

Tags: angular, docker, nestjs, monorepo, nrwl-nx

When I run docker-compose to build a monorepo of Angular and Nest applications through NX, the build is fast but the containers run really slowly. But if I run those applications straight on my mac, it builds really fast. I would like the applications to build faster in docker.

Here you have an example of a service in my docker-compose.yml:

```
  dollop-accounts-web:
    command: npm start dollop-accounts-web
    build:
      args:
        - NODE_VERSION=${NODE_VERSION}
        - PORT=${ACCOUNTS_WEB_PORT}
      context: .
    container_name: dollop-accounts-web
    image: dollop-node-image
    ports:
      - ${ACCOUNTS_WEB_PORT}:${ACCOUNTS_WEB_PORT}
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

And here is my dockerfile that I use for all of my services (notice I copy the whole monorepo for every container because I don't know how to handle this better):

```
ARG NODE_VERSION
ARG PORT
FROM node:$NODE_VERSION
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
EXPOSE $PORT
```

I run 7 services like this and I have this kind of log for a Nest app:

```
> dollop@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> nx serve "dollop-accounts-service"


> nx run dollop-accounts-service:serve 
Starting type checking service...
Using 2 workers with 2048MB memory limit
```

And this kind of log for and Angular App:

```
> dollop@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> nx serve "dollop-tasks-web"


> nx run dollop-tasks-web:serve 
WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
case.
Another process, with id 35, is currently running ngcc.
Waiting up to 250s for it to finish.
(If you are sure no ngcc process is running then you should delete the lock-file at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__.)
```

As you can see, it struggles to start all the apps at once. But even with just one service, it's way slower than when I run on the host. Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: You're not running the code in your image; you're using `volumes:` to overwrite that with some other code.  That's known to be very slow on MacOS.  Delete the `volumes:` and it should run better.  (You can build one image and specify an alternate `command:` for each container you launch from it in the `docker-compose.yml` file.)

Comment: I use docker as a dev environment. So I need to keep the volumes so I don't have to restart the containers for every change. Moreover, I use mongodb, elasticsearch and redis with volumes and they run properly. I tried to remove the volumes and the issue persists. ngcc and typescript type checking can't seem to run on multiple containers at the same time.